Python shortcut for overloading functions over an input union type?
aka: How do I make a function return the same type as an Optional input?
I started with this:
import random
import typing


def get_maybe_str():
    return random.choice([" ", None])

def optional_upper(s: typing.Optional[str]):
    if s is None:
        return s
    return s.upper()


def example(foo:str):
    bar = get_maybe_str()
    if bar is None:
        return
    bar = optional_upper(bar)

    foobar = foo + bar


This results in the static error:

Operator "+" not supported for types "str" and "str | None" Operator "+" not supported for types "str" and "None" PylancereportOperatorIssue

I figured out that this error can be overcome via overloaded function annotations:
@typing.overload
def optional_upper(s: str) -> str: ...

@typing.overload
def optional_upper(s: None) -> None: ...

def optional_upper(s: typing.Optional[str]):
    if s is None:
        return s
    return s.upper()

This works but is very verbose. Is there a simpler way to express this?

This is probably a duplicate of something, but I couldn't find it while googling so I hope posting this can help someone else's searches.

This question is similar to: How can I type-hint a function where the return type depends on the input type of an argument?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Specifically, the second answer.

To indicate that a type used several times in a signature is the same type, a TypeVar can be used.
In this case:
T_OptionalStr = typing.TypeVar('T_OptionalStr', None, str)
 
def optional_upper(s: T_OptionalStr) -> T_OptionalStr:
    if s is None:
        return s
    return s.upper()

To have the intended effect, the return type must be explicitly provided. This would also not work if return s was changed to return None.
VSCode accepts the following variation, but it is rejected by mypy:

T_OptionalStr = typing.TypeVar('T_OptionalStr', bound=typing.Optional[str])


Python 3.12
Python 3.12 provides shortcut syntax for this:
def optional_upper[T: (str,None)](s: T) -> T: 

[T: str|None] would be the same as the invalid bound version.
See also:

(3.10) https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar
(Current >= 3.12) https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar


The constrained type variable works; the bound does not. The new generic syntax shown is equivalent to the bound variable.

With a bound type variable, type narrowing only ensures that return s actually returns None. The type checker still assumes s has type Optional[str] in return s.upper().

@chepner huh you're right. vscode/pylance/pyright was happy with bound, but mypy rejects it

First, be aware that there are two types your function could have:

Callable[[str|none], str|None]: it accepts either a str or a None value, and it returns either a str or a None value, but with no promised correlation between the actual argument type and the actual return type.

Callable[[str], str]] | Callable[[None], None]: if it gets a str, it returns a str, and if it gets None, it returns None.


Your definition implies you want the latter, which is what a constrained type variable is for.
T = TypeVar('T', str, None)

def optional_upper(s: T) -> T
    if s is None:
        return s
    return s.upper()

The type indicates that s can be either None or str, but the return value will have the same type.
The problem with the definition is that if s is None only narrows the type of s inside the block governed by if. It requires additional "simulation" to determine that the second return statement cannot be reached if s is None is true.
Pyright appears to do this work; mypy does not, but you can help it by using an explicit else clause:
T = TypeVar('T', str, None)

def optional_upper(s: T) -> T
    if s is None:
        return s
    else:
        return s.upper()

